# jQuery on responseXML in a Firefox ext

Tags: jquery, firefox-addon, httprequest

I'm trying to allow jQuery 1.4.2 work on a responseXML variable, but it doesn't... I can only let it work with the live page displayed.
Here's my code:

```
var url = myext.baseuri + "/Common/page.asp";
   var httpRequest = myext.createHttpRequest();

   httpRequest.open('GET', url, false);
   httpRequest.send();
   if (httpRequest.status == 200) {

      $h = function(selector,context){ return new jQuery.fn.init(selector,context||httpRequest.responseXML); };

      Firebug.Console.log($h().find("select#id").html());
      Firebug.Console.log($h(httpRequest.responseXML));
      Firebug.Console.log($h(httpRequest.responseXML).html());

   } else {
      Firebug.Console.warn("status "+ httpRequest.status);
   }
```

I see the following results in Firebug console:

- Null
- jQuery(Document )
- Null

I don't understand how I should utilize jQuery in this case... why the first row returns Null?
I really need some help...

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't use html() on XML documents, as it is specified in jQuery documentation : http://docs.jquery.com/Html.

If you want to get the text contained in the "select#id" element, you should try

```
Firebug.Console.log($h("select#id").text());
```

as the text() function can be used on XML documents (cf jQuery documentation).

If you want to get another element of your XML response, you can get it like this :

```
Firebug.Console.log($h("tagName1 tagName2 tagName3"));
```

I haven't tried to get elements by Id like you tried with "#id", but I think that it may be not supported by jQuery for XML document as it calls "document.getElementById()". You may try instead :

```
Firebug.Console.log($h("select[id='id']"));
```

You will not have the same performances with this method, but it may work !

Comment: I've tried with Firebug.Console.log($h("option[value='8']").text()), but I still receive a "" result in Firebug, although a proper value should be displayed (in the responseText, I see that HTML contains the proper <option value="8"> row)... Do you know why?

Comment: Have you tried Firebug.Console.log($h("option[value='8']")); ? You should see an XML element.

Comment: Output is jQuery()... not sure on how to verify that it's a good result. Looking at its properties, I see selector: "option[value='8']", length: 0, jquery: "1.4.2"... nothing that says me it's pointing to the right element...

Comment: Are you sure the httpRequest.responseXML is a document object ?

Comment: Yes, it passes test jQuery.isXMLDoc(httpRequest.responseXML), but it seems that there's a parsererror as a child node... is there anything I can do? Should I use another way to retrieve this page?

Comment: So it seems... if I retrieve it jQuery.ajax(...), there's again an error "parsererror", with a Null XML. Analyzing the page with an HTML Validator, I find 0 errors but over 600 warnings... can it be a reason for failing?

Comment: If the XML is malformed, there's nothing you can do with responseXML I think. By the way, is it XML or HTML you're retrieving ? One solution could be using responseText and then use regex to retrieve the information you want from the string.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of what i am working on :

```
var req = Components.classes["@mozilla.org/xmlextras/xmlhttprequest;1"]
                             .createInstance(Components.interfaces.nsIXMLHttpRequest);
req.onload = function(){
    var xml = req.responseXML;
    $xml = function(selector){ return new jQuery.fn.init(selector,xml); };
    Firebug.Console.log($xml("schedule[order='1'] item"));
};
req.open("GET", url, true);
req.channel.loadFlags |= Components.interfaces.nsIRequest.LOAD_BYPASS_CACHE;
req.send(null);
```

And the Firebug Console :`[item, item, item, item]`

Here is an example of the XML I am working on :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ratp>
    <schedules>
        <schedule order="1">
            <title><![CDATA[Prochains passages en temps réel]]></title>
            <liste>
                <item order="1">
                    <texte1><![CDATA[Voltaire-Villiers]]></texte1>
                    <texte2><![CDATA[11 mn]]></texte2>
                    <texte3><![CDATA[]]>
                    </texte3>
                </item>
                <item order="2">
                    <texte1><![CDATA[Voltaire-Villiers]]></texte1>
                    <texte2><![CDATA[30 mn]]></texte2>
                    <texte3><![CDATA[]]>
                    </texte3>
                </item>
                <item order="3">
                    <texte1><![CDATA[Place Jean Poulmarch]]></texte1>
                    <texte2><![CDATA[4 mn]]></texte2>
                    <texte3><![CDATA[]]>
                    </texte3>
                </item>
                <item order="4">
                    <texte1><![CDATA[Place Jean Poulmarch]]></texte1>
                    <texte2><![CDATA[24 mn]]></texte2>
                    <texte3><![CDATA[]]>
                    </texte3>
                </item>
            </liste>
        </schedule>
    </schedules>
</ratp>
```

Hope it can help !